# Não consigo visualizar a pagina jsp de um projeto Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

Não consigo visualizar a pagina form.jsp

estou colocando a seguinte URL   http://localhost:8080/Loja/

Com essa URL ele somente visualiza a pagina hello-world.jsp

eu até coloco o seguinte endereço  http://localhost:8080/Loja/produtos/form mas gera erro, aonde será que estou errando.

aqui está o meu projeto completo;

https://github.com/wladimirbandeira/Loja/tree/master/Loja

part1;

```
public class ServletSpringMVC extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


    // esse pedaço do código informa qual pagina ira ser mapeada
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {

        return new Class[]{AppWebConfiguration.class};
    }


    // esse código mapea o projeto
    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }
```

part2;

```
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses={HomeController.class})
public class AppWebConfiguration {


    //esse pedaço do código informa aonde está a pagina dentro pacote especifico

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver 
        internalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
```

part3;

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index(){

        System.out.println("carregando produto");
        return "hello-world";// essa é a pagina que está sendo visualizada
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa tarde, grande da uma olhada na tua configuração do arquivo spring.xml e se você configurou a welcome-list-file no web.xml, mas caso a configuração tenha sido feita por classes anotadas ou extendidas (beans) da uma olhada se na classe de configuração do spring mvc você configurou o sufix e o prefix que ele vai informar para o servidor interpretar e se você configurou o welcome file para o que você deseja.

Ok, entendi agora, no caso você precisa adicionar a página que você quer carregar na pasta views, no teu controller quando coloca o `request mapping ("/")` ele está dizendo que toda requisição feita para a url `http://localhost:8080/Loja/` será tratada por aquela classe e no método como o retorno é uma string, esse retorno representa o nome da view que após juntar com o prefix `.jsp` que foi configurado na classe `AppWebConfiguration` ficará hello-world.jsp, ou seja, ele irá carregar na tela a view retornada pelo método, caso você queira subistituir essa view por outra basta implementar um novo método com um outro request mapping ou apenas mudar o retorno para o nome da página que deseja carregar na tela, se você tem uma página index.jsp que queira carregar ela deve estar dentro da pasta views e no retorno do método você deve informar o retorno como index.

Comment: acabei de atualizar minha postagem e coloquei anotações no código para você entender, dá uma olhada por favor para me ajudar melhor